# How to hide the title field in create content?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 6, hooks

I have a type of content that I won't use the page title, 
I will have to use a taxonomy field (the titles will repeat), because it's a restaurant list with auto-complete.

Can I do it with hooks or something?  I could copy some content from other field into the title if it's gonna be mandatory at submit..right?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module in conjunction with the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module is perfect for this.  From the project page:

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
>   data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
>   (since 5.x).
>
> Advanced users can also provide some PHP code, that is used for
>   automatically generating an appropriate title.